# Parse url_encoded_fmt_stream_map

Tags: c++, youtube

I'm trying to parse the url_encoded_fmt_stream_map in c++, because i'm creating a youtube downloader but i have hard time to understand how to parse it.

basically i want to get from this:

```
url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fr3---sn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fkey%253Dyt6%2526ip%253D217.132.162.185%2526pl%253D21%2526itag%253D22%2526dur%253D179.629%2526mv%253Dm%2526source%253Dyoutube%2526ms%253Dau%2526mt%253D1505157185%2526mn%253Dsn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s%2526sparams%253Ddur%25252Cei%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmime%25252Cmm%25252Cmn%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Cpl%25252Cratebypass%25252Crequiressl%25252Csource%25252Cexpire%2526expire%253D1505178857%2526id%253Do-ADSbsO6VmuXG9rLrWKzVyp_ktTQ8sJI4uUZyQZUI3C-k%2526beids%253D%25255B9466593%25255D%2526mime%253Dvideo%25252Fmp4%2526lmt%253D1502272667670502%2526signature%253D969232DFE8D6F9C52BF60808A8E5520603ABC565.791784BF0DFB1E074E9C5F02C312D7918AFBB31E%2526mm%253D31%2526ratebypass%253Dyes%2526requiressl%253Dyes%2526ei%253DieC2WdOQKseNVNfDmeAD%2526initcwndbps%253D1096250%2526ipbits%253D0%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.64001F%252C%2Bmp4a.40.2%2522%26itag%3D22%26quality%3Dhd720%2Curl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fr3---sn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fpl%253D21%2526itag%253D43%2526dur%253D0.000%2526source%253Dyoutube%2526expire%253D1505178857%2526mime%253Dvideo%25252Fwebm%2526lmt%253D1502275397163281%2526ei%253DieC2WdOQKseNVNfDmeAD%2526requiressl%253Dyes%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt6%2526ip%253D217.132.162.185%2526mv%253Dm%2526mt%253D1505157185%2526ms%253Dau%2526beids%253D%25255B9466593%25255D%2526mn%253Dsn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s%2526mm%253D31%2526id%253Do-ADSbsO6VmuXG9rLrWKzVyp_ktTQ8sJI4uUZyQZUI3C-k%2526signature%253D8FC4E9685E7C04DA2B23094E6F0862BA0EF63C5A.BA596770CDCCAB21DC6CCDF3A30FA4CD5D1D5CA6%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cei%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmime%25252Cmm%25252Cmn%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Cpl%25252Cratebypass%25252Crequiressl%25252Csource%25252Cexpire%2526ratebypass%253Dyes%2526clen%253D18425468%2526ipbits%253D0%2526initcwndbps%253D1096250%26type%3Dvideo%252Fwebm%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522vp8.0%252C%2Bvorbis%2522%26itag%3D43%26quality%3Dmedium%2Curl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fr3---sn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fpl%253D21%2526itag%253D18%2526dur%253D179.629%2526source%253Dyoutube%2526expire%253D1505178857%2526mime%253Dvideo%25252Fmp4%2526lmt%253D1502271683313225%2526ei%253DieC2WdOQKseNVNfDmeAD%2526requiressl%253Dyes%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt6%2526ip%253D217.132.162.185%2526mv%253Dm%2526mt%253D1505157185%2526ms%253Dau%2526beids%253D%25255B9466593%25255D%2526mn%253Dsn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s%2526mm%253D31%2526id%253Do-ADSbsO6VmuXG9rLrWKzVyp_ktTQ8sJI4uUZyQZUI3C-k%2526signature%253D20D343F65FE768FD5FF49A09967CECB6A61C335B.33534FA7A420F7A9BEB6FC24D360A0E0C5E11C7B%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cei%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmime%25252Cmm%25252Cmn%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Cpl%25252Cratebypass%25252Crequiressl%25252Csource%25252Cexpire%2526ratebypass%253Dyes%2526clen%253D15476941%2526ipbits%253D0%2526initcwndbps%253D1096250%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.42001E%252C%2Bmp4a.40.2%2522%26itag%3D18%26quality%3Dmedium%2Curl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fr3---sn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fpl%253D21%2526itag%253D36%2526dur%253D179.676%2526source%253Dyoutube%2526expire%253D1505178857%2526mime%253Dvideo%25252F3gpp%2526lmt%253D1502268441956130%2526ei%253DieC2WdOQKseNVNfDmeAD%2526requiressl%253Dyes%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt6%2526ip%253D217.132.162.185%2526mv%253Dm%2526mt%253D1505157185%2526ms%253Dau%2526beids%253D%25255B9466593%25255D%2526mn%253Dsn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s%2526mm%253D31%2526id%253Do-ADSbsO6VmuXG9rLrWKzVyp_ktTQ8sJI4uUZyQZUI3C-k%2526signature%253D3A474A9CFB76C7E27B04210770984E9445E8FDEF.145812E704F0495A1A56EC3499FD5907B0CAF266%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cei%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmime%25252Cmm%25252Cmn%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Cpl%25252Crequiressl%25252Csource%25252Cexpire%2526clen%253D5002143%2526ipbits%253D0%2526initcwndbps%253D1096250%26type%3Dvideo%252F3gpp%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522mp4v.20.3%252C%2Bmp4a.40.2%2522%26itag%3D36%26quality%3Dsmall%2Curl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fr3---sn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fpl%253D21%2526itag%253D17%2526dur%253D179.676%2526source%253Dyoutube%2526expire%253D1505178857%2526mime%253Dvideo%25252F3gpp%2526lmt%253D1502268500455876%2526ei%253DieC2WdOQKseNVNfDmeAD%2526requiressl%253Dyes%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt6%2526ip%253D217.132.162.185%2526mv%253Dm%2526mt%253D1505157185%2526ms%253Dau%2526beids%253D%25255B9466593%25255D%2526mn%253Dsn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s%2526mm%253D31%2526id%253Do-ADSbsO6VmuXG9rLrWKzVyp_ktTQ8sJI4uUZyQZUI3C-k%2526signature%253D4C072B7D94E0C9022A7208257B9F95E8FEF768F4.DB81E33CFA39737AFC9D3072C8A6EF667C75F820%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cei%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmime%25252Cmm%25252Cmn%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Cpl%25252Crequiressl%25252Csource%25252Cexpire%2526clen%253D1808147%2526ipbits%253D0%2526initcwndbps%253D1096250%26type%3Dvideo%252F3gpp%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522mp4v.20.3%252C%2Bmp4a.40.2%2522%26itag%3D17%26quality%3Dsmal
```

to this:

```
https://r3---sn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ip=178.62.189.249&expire=1505177988&ei=JN22Wd2-B8K51gLAm7KoDg&id=o-ALYSMLik_HROZgsaw6ThKLenlUgLey7vPiJRUL1vOrzE&lmt=1502272667670502&requiressl=yes&dur=179.629&pl=21&signature=51AAA75248CF783A1CAEEF9D70BD91812D87A115.57D1E01C85610A81BA5F102C390F49C4E3C6D7BC&ipbits=0&ratebypass=yes&sparams=dur,ei,expire,id,ip,ipbits,ipbypass,itag,lmt,mime,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source&source=youtube&mime=video/mp4&itag=22&key=cms1&redirect_counter=1&req_id=a565fad7c8afa3ee&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mip=217.132.162.185&mm=31&mn=sn-oxu8pnpvo-ua8s&ms=au&mt=1505158540&mv=m
```

can anyone explain how can i do that ?
thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way !

here is a solution:

1. copy the url_encoded_fmt_stream_map to this site: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ (URL Decoder) and click few times on "decoder" until its stop decoding.
2. search for url=XXX and copy it until you see this symbol ; .
3. paste and you can download the video.